# No reconoce actualización 3.6.5

Tags: joomla3

Buenos días
He buscado mucho en la web acerca de esto pero nada que doy con la solución. 
Tengo un site instalado en `XAMPP` es decir es local. Necesito actualizar de `joomla 2.5` a `3.6.5` pero en el administrador, en donde dice **Actualizar Joomla** no reconoce que hay una versión reciente. He tratado con Purgar Cache, con LTS, con STS pero nada. No reconoce actualización alguna. ¿Alguna otra forma que me pueda dar luz?

Comment: En teoría debería funcionar son STS. ¿activaste el reporte máximo de errores? ¿qué versión exacta de 2.5 tienes?

Comment: Hola Shaz, si, ya lo activé pero nada. La version es 2.5.24